# How to find documents that aren't referenced by a document from another collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two models called session and unreadcount. I need to get that particular session count from another table. Below are my two MongoDB models.

```
var UnreadCountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: { type: String, required: true },
    sessionId: { type: String, required: true},
    unreadCount: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0  },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: 0 },
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model("UnreadCount", UnreadCountSchema);

var SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: false },
    subject: { type: String, required: false },
    sessionCode: { type: String, required: false },
}, { timestamps: true });
module.exports = mongoose.model("Session", SessionSchema);
```

I have not used referencing and relation. I need to get a count when I fetch the session. I have tried lookup it doesn't work. Suggest a way to do this.

The following is the code that I executed. The count is there but I am not getting the result.

```
const response = await SessionModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: query,
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "UnreadCount",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "sessionId",
            as: "unreadCounts",
        },
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            unreadCount: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $gt: [{ $size: "$unreadCounts" }, 0] },
                    then: { $arrayElemAt: ["$unreadCounts.unreadCount", 0] },
                    else: 0,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    // Optionally sort the sessions by lastMessage createdAt
    // { $sort: { "lastMessage.createdAt": -1 } },
])
```

Comment: As your `sessionId` stored in `UnreadCount` collection is `string` type. You need to convert it to `ObjectId` to make the equality comparison works. Your `$lookup` stage should be as this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J4lrqqZTSbm)

Comment: @YongShun {
                "$addFields": {
                    "localId": { "$toString": "$_id" }
                }
            }

 i tried using this it also not working

Comment: Can you reproduce with your sample data & query in Mongo Playground?

Comment: @YongShun Thanks it is working now. the demo was very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Wrote the answer from the comment as the answer post*.

Ensure that both fields must have the same type for the equality match. In this case, you can use the [`$lookup` with pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection) to convert the `sessionId` from the UnreadCount collection to `ObjectId`.

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "UnreadCount",
    let: {
      sessionId: "$_id"
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $eq: [
              "$$sessionId",
              {
                $toObjectId: "$sessionId"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "unreadCounts"
  }
}
```

Or you can convert the `_id` from the Session collection as `string` type.

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "UnreadCount",
    let: {
      sessionId: { $toString: "$_id" }
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $eq: [
              "$$sessionId",
              "$sessionId"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "unreadCounts"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we have to use the model name that was created in Mongodb database and also convert the object id to a string. according to the type of data we are going to compare.

The model name mentioned in code was unreadCount in database it was like unreadcounts.

```
{
            $lookup: {
                from: "unreadcounts",
                let: { id: { $toString: "$_id" } },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: ["$sessionId", "$$id"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: "unreadcounts"
            }
        }
```